# oque é SSH, e oque é "putty" relacionado a SSH?

Tags: aplicação-web

Estou aprendendo desenvolvimento web e estou com dificuldades para aprender sobre **SSH**, alguém poderia me explicar de forma completa e já entrando no tema me explicar também o que é o **"putty"** relacionado a tudo isso?

Comment: SSH é um protocolo, putty é um cliente para você conectar em servidores via SSH.

Comment: Sua pergunta está demasiadamente ampla. Se está com dificuldades de entender até o básico de SSH, comece estudando coisas mais básicas, como comunicação e protocolos. Em outras palavras, sua pergunta é do tipo "por favor, me expliquem de forma completa os buracos negros" e poderíamos passar alguns bons meses discutindo isso. Eu recomendaria a você fazer o [tour] e ler o guia de [ask], depois [edit] a sua pergunta e descrever quais foram as suas dificuldades. As respostas dadas atualmente são basicamente o que está na Wikipedia e você provavelmente já leu anteriormente em sua primeira pesquisa.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O SSH (Secure SHell) é um protocolo que permite a você acessar virtualmente o servidor como se você estivesse em um terminal (no prompt do DOS, por exemplo). Se você preferir, considere como o SSH como um computador controlando outro computador.

A diferença entre o telnet e o SSH está na segurança. Toda a transmissão de dados no SSH é criptografada. Assim, os riscos de alguém "bisbilhotar" o que você está fazendo no servidor (às vezes você precisa transmitir senhas para acessar outros sistemas ou programas) é virtualmente zero. Fora isso, tudo o que você faz no telnet pode ser feito pelo SSH.

Quando você conecta via terminal remoto com seu servidor, você está controlando aquele servidor a partir de seu sistema operacional. Qualquer comando que você digitar é executado no servidor (e não no seu PC) e você opera de acordo com os paramêtros de comandos do servidor.

Para acessar o protocolo SSH é necessário um programa que conecte na porta 22.

Ai entra o Putty que é o client para essa conexão

Comment: Algum motivo para downvote

Comment: então pelo que eu entendi o ssh é um terminal que permite que eu me comunique com um servidor "onde esta ospedado meu site no meu caso que seria referente a web" de forma segura, mas não entendi muito bem oque é o putty .